# SQL Query to get Last 1 year data using Year and week number

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SQL query to get data for last year. I don't have a date column in my table, but have `Year` and `WeekNo`. Suppose this is `WeekNo` `26` in `Year` `2017`, I need to get the data from `WeekNo` `26` `Year` `2016` to `WeekNo` `26` `Year` `2017`.

Columns in my table are:

```
Year WeekNo YearWeek(Eg 2016 26) DataX
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: So you want the current week of the current year, back to the same week # of the previous year?

Comment: While I don't have a full answer, do check out the [SQL BETWEEN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) operator, seems relevant.

Comment: If you've tried any queries, please post them.

Comment: Formatting and spelling

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server. Give this a try. This will get you the Week #, Current Year and Previous Year to put into your query.

```
Select DatePart(Week,GetDate()) as WeekNo
, Year(GetDate()) as CurrentYear
, Year(DateAdd(Year,-1,GetDate())) as PreviousYear
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing this might be what you are looking for, assuming SQL Server:

```
Select T1.Year
      ,T1.WeekNo
      ,T1.DataX
From MyTable T1
Where (T1.Year = Year(GetDate()) 
       AND T1.WeekNo <= DatePart(Week,GetDate())
      )
OR (T1.Year = Year(GetDate()) -1
    AND T1.WeekNo >= DatePart(Week,GetDate())
   )
```

This is inclusive of the same week, last year, is your want this to be exclusive of that week, change the ">=" to ">"